# Is there actually any taste (especially flavor) difference between Dalgona method and normal method of making instant cofffee?

Tags: instant, dalgona

The coffee that concerns me is [here](https://www.amazon.in/Nescaf%C3%A9-Classic-Coffee-100g-Glass/dp/B00VK0FTP0/ref=sr_1_8?dchild=1&keywords=nescafe%20classic&qid=1620651620&sr=8-8).

---

**Case 1:** Here's a [video](https://youtu.be/PSf5RCbTtyY?t=142) about Dalgona (most likely it's Dalgona) method coffee.

The video is in Hindi, but I'll translate it in English from 2.35s:

He says, "Let's shuffle/mix it for some time. This shuffling is done because when you do it, the coffee granules/particles release its *flavors*"

And I've heard similar *views* about *flavor* thing heard from a few of my friends.

**Case 2:** One comment under my [this](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/102511/can-you-make-coffee-by-boiling-it) question says you can make this kind of coffee by just adding boiling water and milk and you're done.

> If you're going to use instant coffee, just pour hot water on it, add
> milk to taste, and you're done

---

I can use the method suggested by Chris H, as ingredients are same and it will save a lot of my precious time but I'm just surprised I don't see any tutorial on it on YouTube. So I wonder if it is right method or wrong or it *is* a right method but pretty rare.

Secondly, do both methods actually cause a difference in taste about its flavor or make it more thick? I mean the flavor reason given by the YouTube user is actually a scientific reason? Or could be just his personal opinion?

(Of course, there would be a difference in taste, but I'm more concerned about his *flavor* logic)

---

PS: Why I think that the YouTube user is right about *releasing flavors* thing is because it turns to creamy thing after some time. So it feels like something has chemically changed inside it. So I feel that's the reason it tastes different. But I need to verify this claim.

Comment: Another way to look at this question is whether the amount of flavor improvement, if any, is large enough to make such a complicated process worth the extra effort.

Comment: @ToddWilcox yeah sounds right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first instinct was to answer “no way, that’s instant coffee, where there’s no complex flavor to start with, we can stir the heck out of it and get no change”. On the other side, preparation *can* make a huge difference sometimes, so just dismissing the method shouldn’t be done either. Of course there’s only one way to tell, which is by doing a side-by-side comparison. And that’s what I did.

Setup:

[image]

Two identical cups with one teaspoon instant coffee (Nestlé Gold decaf) and white sugar each. I used a measuring spoon to make sure that each cup had the same amount of product in it.

To one I added one teaspoon of milk and one teaspoon of water, both hot, then manually whisked until a thick and somewhat stable foam formed.

[image]

On previous occasions I used an immersion blender with a whipping disc and could make a stiffer foam. But with the comparatively small amount, that wasn’t an option. Plus the linked video also whisks by hand.

I then poured hot milk and hot water into both cups, using a kitchen scale to ensure that both cups held the same amount and the same ratio.

Initially the whipped cup had a foamy layer that looked good and gave a slightly different mouthfeel. (First taste test.)

[image]

However, the foam started collapsing almost immediately, and about two minutes later, there wasn’t much left. I gently pushed it to one side to show the thickness of the layer.

[image]

I enlisted the help of a family member and did a blind taste test.

And here are the results:

**Without the foam, there’s no taste difference whatsoever between the two methods.**

Frankly, for a plain cup of instant coffee, I wouldn’t bother with all that stirring and whipping.

Comment: First of all thanks for so much "trouble" for this question  I use non gold version of coffee, so this *experiment* should show similar results right? Because I don't think there's much difference between gold and classic.

Comment: You are welcome! No, there shouldn’t be a difference between the various types of instant coffee, apart from slightly different flavors between “classic” and “gold”. You can always repeat my experiment with your own coffee. (I am still saying it’s “just” instant and can’t compete with fresh coffee, but that’s of course personal taste.)

Comment: cool. Also could you tell if that instrument you used blends faster than a spoon?

Comment: with spoon it takes me around 4-7 mins

Comment: But I don't think I'll bother to blend in future much :D

Comment: That’s a small whisk (just like in the video you linked). It *should* be faster. However, I whisked for well over five minutes - and I am quite good at manual whisking.

Comment: Deep down I was also thinking that all difference is of the foam, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, all the method does is aerate the mixture, pre-dissolving the solids slightly.

I can't see how it can possibly affect the flavour unless the resulting 'crema' [for want of a better description] might affect the taste perception, as it does in real coffee. It may make it just look better.

With spray dried coffee there's not much else you can do with it. Nothing is ever going to make it taste like coffee.

Comment: So it is a kind of waste of time spending time in shuffling for 5-10 minutes? :D

Comment: Also, healthline says, "Instant coffee contains slightly less caffeine and more acrylamide than regular coffee, but it contains most of the same antioxidants. Overall, instant coffee is a healthy, low-calorie beverage that is linked to the same health benefits as other types of coffee."

Comment: We don't concern ourselves with 'health benefits' on here, only flavours.

Comment: No problem @Tetsujin

Comment: you may not like the taste of instant coffee but to go so far as to say that it doesn't taste like coffee and nothing will make it taste like coffee is over the top. If you want to say "taste as good as well roasted, well brewed coffee from freshly ground beans" then go ahead, but "doesn't taste like coffee"? come on.

Comment: @KateGregory - It doesn't taste anything like coffee. It may have a similar bitterness, but is has absolutely none of the aroma. Some freeze-drieds have a hint of coffee left in them, but spray dried, none whatsoever. The worst have more in common with gravy browning than coffee.