# Stirring Nescafe before filling the mug

Tags: instant

For several year now I've been making the instant coffee (e.g. Nescafe) as follows: after putting a spoon of coffee I add boiling water just to cover the coffee and stir it with spoon or electrical stirrer. Only after this I fill up the mug and drink.

So my question is: what's the difference (if any) between this method and just filling up the mug with boiling water then stir and drink?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this question and the experiment it prompted](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/5631/1118), I’d say no difference whatsoever.

There’s one small caveat, though: if you happen to have a brand of instant coffee that doesn’t dissolve well, then, and only then, your two-step method may help to avoid any lumps. I have never had any problems, except for once when I had a jar well past its prime where the contents had become somewhat lumpy.